# Angular fire : get the keys,values from map in a document as an observable

Tags: json, angular, database, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

[image: 0th index is number of comments]

This is my firestore document . I want to get the list of comments to an observable, subscribe to that and iterate through the comments. How to do that using angular fire ? 
I am a beginner here so I would be much thankful to you if you could explain this in detail

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On your component.ts file**

```
doc: issue;
doc_comments: Array<string>;
ngOnInit() {
    db.collection('Agriculture_and_cropes').doc<issue>('doc_Id').valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
        this.doc = data;
        this.doc_comments = Array.from( data.comments.keys() );
    });
}
```

**On your component.html**

```
<ul *ngIf="doc_comments">
    <li *ngFor="let c of doc_comments">
        {{c}} : {{doc.comments[c]}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create an observable for a document that emits the document data when there is a change.
Then subscribe to this observable to get the data and display it as you want in your html.
Here is a quick example that can be improved.

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  doc$: Observable<any>;
  collection = 'Agriculture_and_cropes';
  docId = 'Replace by your document Id';

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.doc$ = db.collection(this.collection).doc(this.docId).valueChanges();
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<ul *ngIf="doc$ | async as doc">
  <li *ngFor="let comment of doc.comments">
    {{comment.name}} : {{comment.desc}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's working for me. What is the issue? Did you install [angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md) ?